# MAC Admin user seem as staff

Tags: macos

I began using a colleagues MAC and I am new to MAC. He had the admin rights. I created an account for myself as admin too and I logged in with my own admin account.

But when I use ls -l in lets say '/usr/local/Cellar/' it shows him like this:
his_account admin

When I use ls -l in home directory it shows me like this:
my_account staff

We both have administrator accounts but he is admin, i am staff. I have to be admin too.
I need to brew install something but it says 'Error: Cannot write to /usr/local/Cellar'

I thought it would be because of this admin-staff issue.

Could you help solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting `Terminal` (Cmd+Space, then type `Term` and hit `Enter`). In the Terminal, type

```
sudo su
```

and see if lets you become root (the superuser). If it does, type

```
id
```

and you will see  your id is root (or Admin as you call it). If it is, you can do whatever you want on the machine.

Comment: thanks for the answer, this worked. also, making chown to the /usr/local/Cellar came to my mind and i think it should also work.